# accessing request parameters inside paginator partial

Tags: zend-framework, seo

- 1)how do i access the search `$keyword` inside the paginator partial to create search freindly urls ? clearly, passing the keyword as $this->view->paginator->keyword doesnt work.
- 2) currently, the search button's name is also send as param . for eg when searching for 'a' the url becomes `http://localhost/search/index/search/a/submit//page/2`. any way to stop this ?

Search Form:

---

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="/search">
                        <input id="searchfield" onClick="this.value=''" type="text" name="search" value="Search wallpapers"/>
                        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="" name="submit"/>
                    </form>
```

---

Action inside searchController:

---

```
public function indexAction()
    {        
        $keyword=$this->_request->getParam('search');        
        $alnumFilter=new Zend_Filter_Alnum();
        $dataModel=new Model_data();         

        $adapter=$dataModel->fetchPaginatorAdapter("title LIKE '%".$keyword."%'", '');
        $paginator=new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(18);
        $page=$this->_request->getParam('page', 1);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

        $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
        $this->view->keyword=$keyword;

    }
```

index.phtml (view) file:

---

partialLoop('wallpaper/table-row.phtml',$this->paginator) ;?>

```
    <div id="page-links">

        <?= $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'Sliding','partials/search-pagination-control.phtml');?>       

    </div>
```

search-paginator-control.phtml file:

---

```
if ($this->pageCount){
    $params=Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();


    if(isset($this->previous)){
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($params,array('page'=>$this->previous)));?>">Previous</a>
    <?php
    }
    else{
        ?> Previous <?php
    }

    foreach($this->pagesInRange as $page){
        if($page !=$this->current){
            ?>
        <a href="<?echo $this->url(array_merge($params,array('page'=>$page)));?>"><?=$page;?></a>
        <?
        }
        else{
            echo $page;
        }
    }

    if(isset($this->next)){
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($params,array('page'=>$this->next)));?>">Next</a>
    <?php
    }
    else{
        ?> Next <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The paginationControl view helper accepts a 4th parameter, that is a array of parameters, so in your case you could do something like this:

```
<div id="page-links">

    <?= $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'Sliding','partials/search-pagination-control.phtml', array('keyword' => $this->keyword));?>       

</div>
```

Then you access it inside your pagination using $this->keyword.

Comment: You can also use placeHolder if your variable is use in multiple different partial script http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder

Comment: thanks chris, that did it. do you also happen to know a solution to my second question ?