# How to set up route with parameter when calling pagination controls helper?

Tags: php, routes, pagination, zend-framework2

I am trying to add pagination controls on news page and on news page with specified category.

I have two different routes and actions for simple news feed and news feed with specified news (`news` and `news/category`). I want to add pagination controls to the pages. I found, that I need to do this (in simple news feed case it works):

```
<?=$this->paginationControl(
    $this->news,
    'Sliding',
    'pagination_control',
    array('route' => 'news/pagination')
)?>
```

If I have news feed with specified category I need to change 4th parameter. 
How I call paginationControls helper?:

```
<?=$this->paginationControl(
    $this->news,
    'Sliding',
    'pagination_control',
    array('route' => 'news/category/pagination', array('category' => $this->category->getUrl()))
)?>
```

I am stuck here. I am getting this error:

> Missing parameter "category"

Firstly, I think, that it is not possible to use forth parameter of `paginationControl`, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994358/accessing-request-parameters-inside-paginator-partial) post and in answer to this post I found Chris suggested same approach as I use.

Also, I think this can be caused by this: I am specifying route `news/category/pagination` and send parameter to it, but I have to send this parameter to `news/category`, not `news/category/pagination` (this route doesn't even pass this parameter). Looks like this causing problem.

Anyway, even if I am not mistaken in assumption what caused the error, I don't know how to solve it. Thats the question.

### Update

`news/category/pagination` route config:

```
'news' => array(                                              
    'type' => 'Segment',                                      
    'options' => array(                                       
        'route' => '/news',                                   
        'defaults' => array(                                  
            'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',           
            'action'     => 'index',                          
        ),                                                    
    ),                                                        
    'may_terminate' => true,                                  
    'child_routes' => array(                                  
        // other news child routes,                                                
        'category' => array(                                  
            'type' => 'Segment',                              
            'options' => array(                               
                'route' => '/:category',                      
                'constraints' => array(                       
                    'category'     => '[a-z]+',               
                ),                                            
                'defaults' => array(                          
                    'controller' => 'News\Controller\Item',   
                    'action'     => 'category',               
                )                                             
            ),                                                
            'may_terminate' => true,                          
            'child_routes' => array(                          
                'pagination' => array(                        
                    'type' => 'Segment',                      
                    'options' => array(                       
                        'route' => '/page-:page',             
                        'constraints' => array(               
                            'page'     => '[1-9][0-9]*',      
                        ),                                    
                        'defaults' => array(                  
                            'page'      => 1,                 
                        )                                     
                    ),                                        
                    'may_terminate' => true,                  
                ),                                            
            ),                                                
        ),                                                    
    ),                                                        
),
```

Comment: Your approach seems correct. Can you add the news/category route configuration to the question?

Comment: @foozy I updated my question with route config.